# Should we consider for overflow when use Neon intrinsics such as vadd_s8

Tags: arm, neon

If we have such C code

```
spatial_pred= (cur[mrefs] + cur[prefs])>>1;
```

when transform to Neon intrinsics

```
int8x8_t cur_mrefs = vld1_s8(cur+mrefs);
int8x8_t cur_prefs = vld1_s8(cur+prefs);
int8x8_t spatial_pred = vshr_n_s8(vadd_s8(cur_mrefs, cur_prefs), 1);
```

Do we need to consider for overflow when vadd_s8(cur_mrefs, cur_prefs)? Whether we should use vadd_s16 instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to lose overflow information, you should first [move](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/BABHDBBB.html) `int8x8_t` to `int16x8_t` then do the summing.

If you want result to saturate then you should use [vqadd](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/BABDFJCI.html).

```
Vector saturating add: vqadd -> Vr[i]:=sat<size>(Va[i]+Vb[i])
```

If you just want to convert C version you should use [vhadd](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/BABDFJCI.html) or vrhadd (rounds) which does halving the sum instead of trying to do shift as a second step.

```
Vector halving add: vhadd -> Vr[i]:=(Va[i]+Vb[i])>>1
Vector rounding halving add: vrhadd -> Vr[i]:=(Va[i]+Vb[i]+1)>>1
```